# finding data in JSON object

Tags: arrays, json

In my app there is the following data in a .json config file:

```
"directions": {
  "horizontal": [
    "left",
    "right"
  ],
  "vertical": [
    "down",
    "up"
  ]
}
```

In the app logic, the user selects one of the 4 specific directions (left, right, up, down) from a picker and then the word "horizontal" or "vertical" needs to be displayed in a label based on which option the user chose.  So far, I have this code:
`{{ specificDirection == 'right' ? 'horizontal' : 'other' }}`
which verifies that the label displays the correct info when the user selects `right`.  However, I'm at a loss for how to search the `directions` object in the .json file to find the specific direction in order to get the higher level direction to display in the label.  Is it possible to do this without restructuring the JSON object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach might be something like

```js
const directions = {
    "horizontal": [
      "left",
      "right"
    ],
    "vertical": [
      "down",
      "up"
    ]
};

const queryDirection = "down";
const label = Object.keys(directions)
                .filter(function(lbl) { 
                  return directions[lbl].indexOf(queryDirection) > -1
                })[0];
console.log(queryDirection, '=>', label);
```

This assumes you can guarantee that the query direction will appear in the directions list. Otherwise you will need some safety checking.

Comment: How would this be accomplished with the structure as `const directions = {...`?

Comment: Just use `Object.keys(directions)` in that case. I updated my answer with this approach.

Comment: I added this code to the `created()` hook (this is a Vue Native app).  A console error has popped up: "[Vue warn]: Error in created hook: TypeError: directions[lbl].contains is not a function."

Comment: Edited to use `indexOf` instead

Comment: Good news - there are no console errors.  However, `down => undefined` is being displayed in the console.  I ran `console.log(directions);` to make sure it has access to `directions` and the console correctly displayed the contents of the JSON object.  Got any ideas as to why `label` would be showing as undefined?

Comment: Looks like I got too used to writing in lambdas; needed to add a return statement. Works okay in the test I just ran. Hopefully that fixes it.